Understanding the quotient from $Top$ to $hTop$ categorically
Considering that a point $x:X$ is equivalent to a map $x:1\rightarrow X$, and that paths between points $p(0)=x,p(1)=y$ are equivalent to homotopies between such maps $H(*,0)=x,H(*,1)=y$, we can generalize $\pi_0 : Top \rightarrow Set$ to $\pi_0 : Top^{op}\times Top \rightarrow Set$, that picks two spaces $X$ and $Y$ and gives the quotient on maps from $X$ to $Y$
$$\pi_0(X,Y) := Top(X,Y)/\sim$$
for $f\sim g$ iff there is a homotopy between them.
You recover the usual $\pi_0$ if the first space is the space with one point, $1$.
It is indeed a functor by sending $(u:X\leftarrow X',v:Y\rightarrow Y')$ and a homotopy $H$ to a homotopy $v\circ H(-,t)\circ u$.
In general, it is the $Hom$ functor of $hTop$.

I'm trying to understand the quotient from above in more categorical terms. Maybe as a pullback or equalizer.
I know there's a way to do this in general for concrete categories by taking the equalizer of the projections of the relation $\sim\subseteq Top(X,Y)\times Top(X,Y)$, but I'm looking for something that generalizes easily and doesn't rely on particularities of implementations in $Set$.
I tried a few things, but ended up a bit lost.
Thanks in advance for any help!

A way to view this categorically/abstractly is via model categories. That is probably not what you want, but model categories are actually quite useful.

@LukasHeger I've heard that name before, but don't know quite what they are. They don't look particularly hard, but it would still take me a bit to see how to use them for this example. (Thanks for the comment anyway, they do look interesting. :D )

An immediate issue with generalizing this idea is that you have to decide what a "homotopy" is, which is what Lukas Heger's comment, and answer, address. I think your question could use some clarification regarding what precisely it is you want to generalize. Do you want to stick with Top, and the usual homotopies, and give some more "universal" description of the homotopy category? Or do are you asking about doing this for categories other than Top?

The following kind of answers your question, but is probably not the kind of answer you're looking for. I hope these ramblings are still interesting enough to be mentioned.
First approach:
Let $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$ be two monoidal categories (all tensor products will just be denoted by $\otimes$). Then any lax monoidal functor $F:\mathcal V \to \mathcal W$ induces a ($2$-)functor from the ($2$-)categories of $\mathcal V$-enriched categories to the ($2$-)category of $\mathcal W$-enriched categories. This ($2$-)functor is construcetd as follows: take any $\mathcal V$-enriched category $\mathcal C$, then we define $\mathcal F(\mathcal C)$ to be the $\mathcal W$-enriched category given as follows: we take the same objects as $\mathcal C$ and define $\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal F(\mathcal C)}(x,y)=F(\mathbf{Hom}_C(x,y))$ and we use the structure of $F$ as a lax monoidal functor to get everything else we need (composition, associator, unit, unitor).
Now $\mathbf{Top}$ is a closed monoidal category using the cartesian product as the tensor product, via the compact-open topology. $\mathbf{Set}$ is a monoidal category wrt the cartesian product. The functor $\pi_0:\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ sends products to products and is hence (even strictly) monoidal. Thus we can apply the general nonsense from above, as $\mathbf{Top}$  is itself a $\mathbf{Top}$-enriched category, as it's closed monoidal. This will yield the category $\mathbf{hTop}$ that we're after just from the functor $\pi_0:\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$. All these complicated words are just saying in our concrete case that (using your notation) $\pi_0(X,Y)=\pi_0(\mathbf{Map}(X,Y))$, where $\mathbf{Map}(X,Y)$ is the topological space of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$.
Second Approach:
Again, let's generalize the setup quite a bit. Let's suppose we have some category $\mathcal C$ with some kind of class of morphisms $\mathcal W \subset \mathbf{Mor}(\mathcal C)$. We want to find a "universal solution" to the problem of finding a category $\mathcal D$ together with a functor $F:\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ such that $F(f)$ is an isomorphism for all $f$. Before you ask what this has to do with our situation, let's consider the striking similarity to the universal property of the localization of a ring!
In our case, we have $\mathcal C=\mathbf{Top}$ and $\mathcal W$ consists of all homotopy equivalences. This may look a bit mysterious right now, but the theory of model categories demystifies this. (Or maybe I'm not seeing a simple argument right now.)

This does not contradict the spirit of you answer, but $\mathbf{Top}$ is not cartesian closed. The identity $\pi_0(X,Y)=\pi_0(\mathbf{Map}(X,Y))$ holds anyhow cause $I$ is compact.

@Thorgott you're right. Everything should work fine for compactly generated spaces.
